# Problema com Encoding

Tags: r

Eu estou fazendo um trabalho na faculdade que tive que fazer uma pesquisa de opinião, e para isso usei o Google Forms para fazer esse trabalho. Após colhidas as respostas fui importar o arquivo usando o `read_xlsx` e tive um problema de enconding:

```
base <- read_xlsx("Banco/Trabalho 3/base1.xlsx")
```

Como poderia resolver isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
```
    dput(head(base, 20))

> base<-read_xlsx("Banco/Trabalho 3/base.xlsx")
>   dput(head(base, 20))
>   structure(list(sexo = c("Masculino", "Masculino", "Masculino", 
>   "Masculino", "Masculino", "Masculino", "Masculino", "Masculino", 
>   "Masculino", "Masculino", "Masculino", "Masculino", "Masculino", 
>   "Masculino", "Masculino", "Masculino", "Masculino", "Masculino", 
>   "Masculino", "Masculino"), idade = c(13, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 
>   14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14), escolaridade = c("Ensino Fundamental - Completo", 
>   "Ensino Fundamental - Completo", "Ensino Fundamental - Completo", 
>   "Ensino Fundamental - Completo", "Ensino Fundamental - Completo", 
>   "Ensino Fundamental - Completo", "Ensino Fundamental - Completo", 
>   "Ensino Fundamental - Completo", "Ensino Fundamental - Completo", 
>   "Ensino Fundamental - Completo", "Ensino Fundamental - Completo", 
>   "Ensino Fundamental - Completo", "Ensino Fundamental - Completo", 
>   "Ensino Fundamental - Completo", "Ensino Fundamental - Completo", 
>   "Ensino Fundamental - Completo", "Ensino Fundamental - Completo", 
>   "Ensino Fundamental - Completo", "Ensino Fundamental - Completo", 
>   "Ensino Fundamental - Completo"), civil = c("Casado(a) ou Unio Estvel", 
>   "Casado(a) ou Unio Estvel", "Casado(a) ou Unio Estvel", 
>   "Casado(a) ou Unio Estvel", "Casado(a) ou Unio Estvel", 
>   "Casado(a) ou Unio Estvel", "Casado(a) ou Unio Estvel", 
>   "Casado(a) ou Unio Estvel", "Casado(a) ou Unio Estvel", 
>   "Casado(a) ou Unio Estvel", "Casado(a) ou Unio Estvel", 
>   "Casado(a) ou Unio Estvel", "Casado(a) ou Unio Estvel", 
>   "Casado(a) ou Unio Estvel", "Casado(a) ou Unio Estvel", 
>   "Casado(a) ou Unio Estvel", "Casado(a) ou Unio Estvel", 
>   "Casado(a) ou Unio Estvel", "Casado(a) ou Unio Estvel", 
>   "Casado(a) ou Unio Estvel"), estado = c("Gois", 
>   "So Paulo", "So Paulo", "Minas Gerais", "So Paulo", 
>   "Paran", "So Paulo", "So Paulo", "Minas Gerais", 
>   "So Paulo", "Piau", "Mato Grosso", "So Paulo", 
>   "So Paulo", "So Paulo", "Rio Grande do Sul", 
>   "Rio Grande do Sul", "So Paulo", "Rio Grande do Sul", 
>   "So Paulo"), genero_jogo = c("FPS (First Person Shooter) / TPS (Third Person Shooter), MMORPG (Massive Multiplayer Online Role Playing Game), Simuladores, Esportes, Luta", 
>   "Ao e Aventura", "FPS (First Person Shooter) / TPS (Third Person Shooter), RPG (Role Playing Game), MOBA (Multiplayer Online Battle Arena), Battle Royale, Esportes", 
>   "FPS (First Person Shooter) / TPS (Third Person Shooter), Battle Royale", 
>   "FPS (First Person Shooter) / TPS (Third Person Shooter), RPG (Role Playing Game)", 
>   "FPS (First Person Shooter) / TPS (Third Person Shooter), Simuladores, Esportes", 
>   "FPS (First Person Shooter) / TPS (Third Person Shooter), Battle Royale", 
>   "FPS (First Person Shooter) / TPS (Third Person Shooter), RPG (Role Playing Game), Simuladores, Ao e Aventura, Puzzle", 
>   "FPS (First Person Shooter) / TPS (Third Person Shooter), Simuladores", 
>   "FPS (First Person Shooter) / TPS (Third Person Shooter), MOBA (Multiplayer Online Battle Arena)", 
>   "FPS (First Person Shooter) / TPS (Third Person Shooter), MOBA (Multiplayer Online Battle Arena)", 
>   "FPS (First Person Shooter) / TPS (Third Person Shooter), MMORPG (Massive Multiplayer Online Role Playing Game), Battle Royale, Ao e Aventura, Puzzle", 
>   "FPS (First Person Shooter) / TPS (Third Person Shooter)", "FPS (First Person Shooter) / TPS (Third Person Shooter)", 
>   "FPS (First Person Shooter) / TPS (Third Person Shooter)", "FPS (First Person Shooter) / TPS (Third Person Shooter), Battle Royale, Simuladores, Ao e Aventura", 
>   "FPS (First Person Shooter) / TPS (Third Person Shooter), Esportes", 
>   "FPS (First Person Shooter) / TPS (Third Person Shooter), Battle Royale, Luta", 
>   "FPS (First Person Shooter) / TPS (Third Person Shooter), MOBA (Multiplayer Online Battle Arena), Esportes, Luta", 
>   "FPS (First Person Shooter) / TPS (Third Person Shooter), Battle Royale"
>   ), horas_semana = c("de 4  6 horas", "de 4  6 horas", 
>   "mais de 6 horas", "mais de 6 horas", "de 4  6 horas", 
>   "mais de 6 horas", "mais de 6 horas", "de 4  6 horas", 
>   "mais de 6 horas", "mais de 6 horas", "de 4  6 horas", 
>   "de 4  6 horas", "mais de 6 horas", "de 2  4 horas", 
>   "mais de 6 horas", "mais de 6 horas", "de 2  4 horas", 
>   "mais de 6 horas", "mais de 6 horas", "mais de 6 horas"), plataforma = c("PC (Steam, Origin, Uplay, etc)", 
>   "PS3 / PS4 / PS4 Pro", "PC (Steam, Origin, Uplay, etc), PS3 / PS4 / PS4 Pro, Celular e Portteis", 
>   "PC (Steam, Origin, Uplay, etc), PS3 / PS4 / PS4 Pro, Celular e Portteis", 
>   "PC (Steam, Origin, Uplay, etc), Celular e Portteis", 
>   "PC (Steam, Origin, Uplay, etc)", "PC (Steam, Origin, Uplay, etc), Xbox 360 / Xbox One / Xbox One X / Xbox One S, Celular e Portteis", 
>   "PC (Steam, Origin, Uplay, etc), Celular e Portteis", 
>   "PC (Steam, Origin, Uplay, etc), PS3 / PS4 / PS4 Pro, Celular e Portteis", 
>   "PC (Steam, Origin, Uplay, etc), Xbox 360 / Xbox One / Xbox One X / Xbox One S", 
>   "Celular e Portteis", "PC (Steam, Origin, Uplay, etc), Wii / Wii U / Switch, Celular e Portteis", 
>   "PC (Steam, Origin, Uplay, etc), Xbox 360 / Xbox One / Xbox One X / Xbox One S, Celular e Portteis", 
>   "PC (Steam, Origin, Uplay, etc), Xbox 360 / Xbox One / Xbox One X / Xbox One S, PS3 / PS4 / PS4 Pro, Celular e Portteis", 
>   "PC (Steam, Origin, Uplay, etc), Xbox 360 / Xbox One / Xbox One X / Xbox One S, Celular e Portteis", 
>   "PS3 / PS4 / PS4 Pro, Celular e Portteis", "PC (Steam, Origin, Uplay, etc), Xbox 360 / Xbox One / Xbox One X / Xbox One S, Celular e Portteis", 
>   "PC (Steam, Origin, Uplay, etc), Xbox 360 / Xbox One / Xbox One X / Xbox One S", 
>   "PC (Steam, Origin, Uplay, etc), PS3 / PS4 / PS4 Pro, Celular e Portteis", 
>   "PC (Steam, Origin, Uplay, etc), Celular e Portteis"), 
>       p_venda = c("No", "Sim", "No", "Sim", "No", 
>       "Sim", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
>       "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
>       "No", "No", "No", "No", "No"
>       ), preco_jogos = c("No", "No", "No", 
>       "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
>       "No", "No", "No", "No", "Sim", 
>       "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
>       "No", "No"), midia = c("Fsica", "Fsica", 
>       "Fsica, Digital", "Digital", "Digital", "Digital", 
>       "Digital", "Digital", "Digital", "Fsica", "Fsica, Digital", 
>       "Digital", "Digital", "Digital", "Fsica", "Fsica, Digital", 
>       "Digital", "Digital", "Fsica, Digital", "Digital"
>       ), produtos = c("Merchandising (Camisas, Pelcias, Action Figures, etc...)", 
>       "Nenhum", "DLC (Downloadable Content) / Season Pass, Skins", 
>       "Skins", "Skins, Aprimoramentos (XP Boost, Gold Boost, etc...)", 
>       "DLC (Downloadable Content) / Season Pass, Skins", "Skins", 
>       "DLC (Downloadable Content) / Season Pass", "Nenhum", "Skins", 
>       "Skins, Aprimoramentos (XP Boost, Gold Boost, etc...)", "DLC (Downloadable Content) / Season Pass, Skins", 
>       "Skins", "Skins, Merchandising (Camisas, Pelcias, Action Figures, etc...)", 
>       "Skins", "DLC (Downloadable Content) / Season Pass", "Skins, Aprimoramentos (XP Boost, Gold Boost, etc...)", 
>       "Skins", "Skins, Merchandising (Camisas, Pelcias, Action Figures, etc...)", 
>       "Outros"), evento = c("Sim", "Sim", "No", "Sim", 
>       "Sim", "Sim", "No", "Sim", "No", "No", 
>       "No", "Sim", "No", "No", "No", 
>       "No", "No", "No", "Sim", "Sim"), 
>       dinheiro = c("Sim", "Sim", "No", "Sim", "Talvez", 
>       "No", "Sim", "No", "No", "Talvez", 
>       "No", "Talvez", "Sim", "Sim", "Talvez", "Talvez", 
>       "Talvez", "No", "Talvez", "No"), jogabilidade = c("Alta Importncia", 
>       "Alta Importncia", "Alta Importncia", "Alta Importncia", 
>       "Mdia Importncia", "Alta Importncia", 
>       "Alta Importncia", "Alta Importncia", "Mdia Importncia", 
>       "Alta Importncia", "Alta Importncia", "Alta Importncia", 
>       "Mdia Importncia", "Alta Importncia", 
>       "Mdia Importncia", "Alta Importncia", 
>       "Alta Importncia", "Alta Importncia", "Alta Importncia", 
>       "Alta Importncia"), grafico = c("Mdia Importncia", 
>       "Alta Importncia", "Mdia Importncia", 
>       "Mdia Importncia", "Mdia Importncia", 
>       "Mdia Importncia", "Mdia Importncia", 
>       "Baixa Importncia", "Mdia Importncia", 
>       "Mdia Importncia", "Mdia Importncia", 
>       "Alta Importncia", "Mdia Importncia", 
>       "Baixa Importncia", "Baixa Importncia", "Mdia Importncia", 
>       "Mdia Importncia", "Mdia Importncia", 
>       "Mdia Importncia", "Mdia Importncia"
>       ), multiplayer = c("Mdia Importncia", "Baixa Importncia", 
>       "Alta Importncia", "Alta Importncia", "Mdia Importncia", 
>       "Mdia Importncia", "Alta Importncia", 
>       "Mdia Importncia", "Mdia Importncia", 
>       "Alta Importncia", "Alta Importncia", "Alta Importncia", 
>       "Alta Importncia", "Alta Importncia", "Alta Importncia", 
>       "Mdia Importncia", "Alta Importncia", 
>       "Alta Importncia", "Mdia Importncia", 
>       "Mdia Importncia"), multiplayer_c = c("Mdia Importncia", 
>       "Baixa Importncia", "Alta Importncia", "Alta Importncia", 
>       "Alta Importncia", "Alta Importncia", "Alta Importncia", 
>       "Baixa Importncia", "Mdia Importncia", 
>       "Alta Importncia", "Alta Importncia", "Baixa Importncia", 
>       "Alta Importncia", "Alta Importncia", "Alta Importncia", 
>       "Alta Importncia", "Mdia Importncia", 
>       "Alta Importncia", "Mdia Importncia", 
>       "Mdia Importncia"), tempo_jogo = c("Alta Importncia", 
>       "Alta Importncia", "Mdia Importncia", 
>       "Alta Importncia", "Mdia Importncia", 
>       "Mdia Importncia", "Baixa Importncia", 
>       "Mdia Importncia", "Baixa Importncia", 
>       "Baixa Importncia", "Mdia Importncia", 
>       "Alta Importncia", "Baixa Importncia", "Baixa Importncia", 
>       "Baixa Importncia", "Mdia Importncia", 
>       "Mdia Importncia", "Mdia Importncia", 
>       "Baixa Importncia", "Mdia Importncia"
>       ), requisitos = c("Sim", "No", "Sim", "No", 
>       "No", "No", "Sim", "Sim", "Sim", "No", 
>       "Sim", "Sim", "No", "No", "Sim", "No", 
>       "Sim", "Sim", "Sim", "Sim"), divertimento = c("Alta Importncia", 
>       "Alta Importncia", "Alta Importncia", "Alta Importncia", 
>       "Mdia Importncia", "Alta Importncia", 
>       "Mdia Importncia", "Alta Importncia", 
>       "Alta Importncia", "Mdia Importncia", 
>       "Alta Importncia", "Alta Importncia", "Alta Importncia", 
>       "Alta Importncia", "Baixa Importncia", "Alta Importncia", 
>       "Alta Importncia", "Mdia Importncia", 
>       "Mdia Importncia", "Alta Importncia"
>       )), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
>   ))```

**OBS; Não sei se esta informação é relevante mas o formulário foi feito no PC que rodava Linux e estou abrindo esse arquivo num Mac**

Comment: Pode, por favor, **editar a pergunta** com a saída de `dput(base)` ou, se a base for muito grande, de `dput(head(base, 20))`?

Comment: Gabriel, poste o código, não seu print.

Comment: Peço desculpa pelos erros mas não mexer muito no Stack

Comment: Achei um solução no Stack gringo, segue o link [Solução][1]
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23324872/rstudio-not-picking-the-encoding-im-telling-it-to-use-when-reading-a-file

Comment: Resposta do próprio autor da pergunta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23324872/rstudio-not-picking-the-encoding-im-telling-it-to-use-when-reading-a-file